# Remove unnessecary Spaces in ListView of Images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I am rendering a `ListView` that consists of image. I wish to get rid to the plane grey color. How do I get rid of that ? Seems, to be weird and rather easy one but I am unable to figure out the solution.

[image]

**list_View.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#A4A4A4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageStatus"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, paste some code maybe ? I can make 10 guesses on the cause of this by just looking at the picture.

Comment: @g00dy please check the edits

Comment: Maybe set the background of the `LinearLayout` to `color/transparent` ? Is this one image which is visualized above, I mean I see "Zombies" and "Virus", but are those two images or one whole ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageStatus"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" <!-- This will Help you  -->
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

You can also set Minimum Width & Height using >>>

```
android:minHeight="120dp" 
android:minWidth="100dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code to the following in the listview:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this as an attribute to your image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
     ...>

    <ImageView
        ...
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

</LinearLayout>
```